# Extra argument 'completion' in call in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am totally new in Swift language ..I have written function with completion block

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

struct ConnectionManager {
func callGetMethod(url:NSString , completion:(responseData:AnyObject,errorMessage:NSError)->Void)
{

    let urlObj = NSURL(string: url)!

    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlObj).responseJSON() {
        (_, _, data, error) in

        completion( responseData: data!, errorMessage: error!)

        println(data)
    }
}
}
```

and calling from my viewcontroller but i am getting error Extra argument  compilation in call  .

```
 var stringurl="http://"

 ConnectionManager.callGetMethod(url:stringurl,completion:{(responseData,errorMessage) in

    })
```

[image]
 Please advise me ..
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 issues in your call:

1. In your completion block you didn't included the tuple
2. No need to include that `url` (first argument label)
3. You declared `callGetMethod` as a member function and you are calling that with struct name not by it's object. If you need to call it by struct name make it as static

Change the implementation to:

```
struct ConnectionManager
{
   static func callGetMethod(url:NSString , completion:(responseData:AnyObject,errorMessage:NSError)->Void)
   {
   }
}
```

You need to change the call to:

```
ConnectionManager.callGetMethod("", completion: { (responseData, errorMessage) -> Void in

})
```

Also the issue is you de

Comment: @Kalpesh: Are you using above mentioned code ? there is no `url` argument label in my code